# error: non-static method getActivity() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, class, android-fragmentactivity, android-context

error: incompatible types: tab1 cannot be converted to Context
`private Context context = tab1.this;`
tab1 is a fragment class

Comment: The title and question are different.

Comment: You can get the context using fragment.getContext();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragment` can't be cast to `Context`. You need to call `getActivity()` on its instance.

```
private Context context = tab1.getActivity();
```

I see the title of the question though which says non-static method `getActivity()` can't be referenced. There is no info on this in the question. But you shouldn't have `Context` in static methods and references as it's going to cause a memory leak. Please get rid of static references and just call `getActivity()` from non-static method.